# How to pass function to createEmbeddedView in structure directive?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

Template where directive is used:

```
<select>
  <ng-container *range="[1998, 2016]; let num; let fn = fn">
    <option (click)="fn()" [ngValue]="num">{{ num }} {{ fn | json }}</option>
  </ng-container>
</select>
```

Directive is:

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[range]"
})
export class RangeDirective {
  _range: number[];

  constructor(private vcr: ViewContainerRef, private tpl: TemplateRef<any>) {}

  @Input()
  set range(value) {
    this.vcr.clear();
    this._range = this.generateRange(value[0], value[1]);
    this._range.forEach(num => {
      this.vcr.createEmbeddedView(this.tpl, {
        $implicit: num,
        fn: submit
      });
    });
  }

  private generateRange(from, to) {
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = from; i <= to; i++) {
      arr.push(i);
    }

    return arr;
  }
}
```

Function is:

```
let submit = () => {
  alert("Submit event");
};
```

**My idea is to dynamically change handler click**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
(click)="fn"
```

should be

```
(click)="fn()"
```

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqb7vr)

## Edit

The other issue that you are having is that browsers do not emit `click` events from `<option>` elements. There are two alternatives that I can think of:

### Option 1 - `<select>` `change` event:

```
<select #select (change)="onChange(select.value)">
  ...
  <option value="a">A</option>
  ...
</select>
```

Unfortunately it is not possible to assign objects to `<option>` elements, therefore this approach does not help you because it is not possible to pass a function to the `change` event handler that is unique to each option.

### Option 2 - `ngModelChange`:

This approach should do what you want to do:

```
<select ngModel (ngModelChange)="$event.fn(); onChange($event.value)">
  <option *range="[1998, 2016]; let num; let fn = fn" [ngValue]e="{ fn: fn, value: num }">{{ num }}</option>
</select>
```

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9gyeaz)

Comment: Do I pass parameters right? ` {
        $implicit: num,
        fn: fn
      }`

Comment: Could you see my full example, I have updated question with your recommendations